# pangolin : No known video handler for URI 'convert'

Tags: 14.04, video, webcam

I was trying to execute an example program called Simple Record in Pangolin tool(lightweight portable rapid development library for managing OpenGL display / interaction and abstracting video input) on Ubuntu 14.04LTS using a webcam logitech c170. I get this error and the program terminates:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>    'pangolin::VideoExceptionNoKnownHandler'
>   what():  No known video handler for URI 'convert' Aborted (core dumped)
>
> command used to execute is: ./SimpleRecord convert:[fmt=RGB24]//v4l:///dev/video0 /home/Output/out.mp4

Webcam is getting detected by the system,when I execute the cmd:
$v4l2-ctl --list-devices
 Webcam C170 (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2):
    /dev/video0
I might be missing something.Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: this is not really an Ubuntu specific question, however.... notice the error "No known video handler for URI 'convert' " maybe try something like  $ ./SimpleRecord [fmt=RGB24]//v4l:///dev/video0 /home/Output/out.mp4  or $ ./SimpleRecord -convert v4l:[fmt=RGB24]//dev/video0 /home/Output/out.mp4 ,.....basically my guess is that convert being part of the uri is your problem....

Comment: @Joshua :Thank you so much for the reply :). I tried the above but no luck.I see that convert here is actually a function which calls ffmpeg and when I run the cmd without args I get this : ./SimpleRecord                                                   Usage  : SimpleRecord [video-uri] [output-uri]                                                Where video-uri describes a stream or file resource, e.g.
 dc1394:[fmt=RGB24,size=640x480,fps=30,iso=400,dma=10]//0
 v4l:///dev/video0
 convert:[fmt=RGB24]//v4l:///dev/video0  .. I  get the same error even when the  webcam is disconnected.

Comment: how about something like this " ./SimpleRecord  v4l://dev/video0 convert:/home/Output/out.mp4 " or just " SimpleRecord /dev/video0 /home/Output/out.mp4 "

Comment: Thank you for your time!! using ./SimpleRecord v4l://dev/video0 convert:/home/Output/out.mp4 throws the exeception   what():  Cannot stat device .No such file or directory  Unsupported image file type,  using ./SimpleRecord /dev/video0 /home/Output/out.mp4 throws an execption what():  Unsupported image file type, '/dev/video0'

Comment: for sure your webcam is at /dev/video0 ?

Comment: yes ... The ouput of the  cmd v4l2-ctl --list-devices  is Webcam C170 (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2):
 /dev/video0 and when the camera is being used by other application, it throws an error saying device is busy

Comment: is there a way I can look at the simple record script? is there a readme?

Comment: There is a readme for the Pangolin tool as a whole, https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin and I'm trying to execute an example program called Simple Record. Yes! Script is available at https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/blob/master/examples/SimpleRecord/main.cpp

Comment: hrm... looks like your original command was correct... do you have ffmpeg installed ( sudo apt install ffmpeg )

Comment: also... this command might work ./SimpleRecord v4l:///dev/video0 /home/Output/out.mp4

Comment: Thank you for your time! Yes I have installed ffmpeg but only the readme mentioned dependencies . The above cmd also throws a similar exception.

Comment: are you able to view video OK with other aps from your cam?

Comment: Thank you :) Adding few more ffmpeg libraries seem to work! The video gets recorded and I am able to play it .I added libavdevice-dev, libavfilter-dev,l ibv4l-dev. But I still get another exception : No known video handler for URI 'file'(format to specify the output file, file:///home/out.avi). Now convert: is being recognized but file still isn't.So I was thinking it's due other dependencies in ffmpeg ? 
  Yes! I have used GTK UVC video viewer and cheese to test.

Comment: instead of file:///blah/blah.mp4 did you just try /blah/blah.mp4 ... going to put findings into answer.

Answer (score 0):

For video conversion one needs to install ffmpeg and various dependencies. Depending on what you are using you might need many of the libav and libv4l dependencies.

You can search for what you need with apt-cache:

```
apt-cache search libav
apt-cache search libv4l
```

This will give a list and description of available installs.

Looking at the code for SimpleRecord,

```
 ./SimpleRecord convert:[fmt=RGB24]//v4l:///dev/video0 /home/Output/out.mp4
```

is the correct syntax for calling the program.